# IntelliJ IDEA heap size, initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size

Tags: java, memory, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I'm a beginner in Java, and I just started using IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.

When I use it, sometimes it's delayed.

I changed my `xms` and `xmx` for larger heap size (xms = 1024, xmx = 2048), but it throws an error. So, I rolled it back.

The error message was something like this: "Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size". What is the problem?

If possible, how do I increase maximum heap size?

I'm using a laptop and it has 8GB memory, x64 IntelliJ.exe used.

Answer (score 20):

If you are seeing this error in InteliJ after the 2019.2 update it is because the update changed the JVM XMX value to 2048m without checking the related values which can allow XMS to become larger than the max XMX value which is not valid and creates that error.

i.e.  The values for me had been XMX=6000m and XMS=4096m but after the 2019.2 update they were XMX=2048m and XMS=4096m

You will have to manually change the values so XMS is equal to or less than XMX.  On Macs the VM options file is  ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.2/idea.vmoptions

NOTE:  That path assumes you are on InteliJ version 2019.2.   You will need to change that value in the path to the version you are on if

Comment: A restart is required.  
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > **Just Restart**. For me the file was in `~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/<version>/bin`.

Comment: I was on version 2019.2.4 running on Windows 10, then upgraded to 2019.3 and got this bug. Trying to start it using the "exe" files did not output any errors, even in cmd and powershell. I got the message about memory by executing the included "idea.bat". I checked my idea64.vm.options files and everything looked correct. Thanks to @Mijo, I checked the file under my user profile. It changed "-Xmx4096m" to "-Xmx2038m"; That's right ... "-Xmx2038m" ... .  I had "-Xms2048m" as the minimal startup memory.

Comment: Correct path: _~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2019.2/idea.vmoptions_

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue on Linux. The configuration file is found in 
`~/.IntelliJIdea2018.2/config/idea64.vmoptions`
The directory will look like ~/.IntelliJIdeayyyy.n/config where yyyy is the year, and n is the release number in that year.
Make sure that the 
`-Xms` value is higher than the `-Xmx`
Here is my working config for ubuntu 18.04 with 8GB RAM

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-server
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:NewSize=1024m
-XX:MaxNewSize=1512m
-XX:NewRatio=1
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=65
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:-TraceClassUnloading
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
```

Comment: ake sure that the -Xms value is **lower** than or equals to the -Xmx

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in IntelliJ in MAC.

There is a build process heap size configuration in IntelliJ. You can find this setting in

> **Preferences > Compiler > Build Process Heap Size**

Make sure the Xmx value(in the environment or VM options) is lower than the value in settings. If not either increase **Build Process Heap Size** in IntelliJ settings or reduce Xmx value in VM options.

By default **Build Process Heap Size** will be 700m.

Answer (score 0):

Use Help | [Edit Custom VM Options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869), change `-Xmx` value only to `2GB` or whatever value you need, `-Xms` value should be lower or the same. Note that too high heap can make GC pauses much longer.

You problem may be not related to memory settings at all. The proper way of reporting performance issues is [described in this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235). You need to capture a CPU snapshot and submit it to JetBrains support or the issue tracker.