# PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2-Out of Memory and weird behavour on large files

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

Out of memory when I try to load big excel file to my python script

first, I using PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.

I go to Help-Edit Custom VM Options.

I try to change the Xmx value to a bigger value.

After I change the xmx value my phaycharm going crush.

my questions are:

A.what is the maximum value for the Xms, Xmx that I can put into the pycharm

(i have strong PC)

B.what is the amount of the biggest file that I can load in my script

Comment: please go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53148782/9526947)

Comment: If you receive OOM error while running python, it has nothing common with PyCharm settings, it seems that your script consumes big amount of memory.