# "Initial heap size set to a larger value than the max heap size" Error With Intellij 2019.2.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am facing a problem with Intellij 2019.2.1 version to which I recently upgraded. I have set up the Xms and Xmx in the Intellij Help -> Edit Custom vm options and I have also manually set up the same properties in idea64.exe.vmoption and idea.exe.vmoption as well. like below :-
-Xms128m
-Xmx10g

Now, when I am starting my application, in the VM argument of the application I am passing -Xmx800m then on runing the application it throwing an error stating that "Initial heap size set to a larger value than the max heap size".

Could some one please suggest what wrong configuration I am putting here or am I missing something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij heap size, Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066443/intellij-heap-size-initial-heap-size-set-to-a-larger-value-than-the-maximum-hea)

Comment: none of the solution is working as I have already updated evey vm options manually

Answer (score 1):

1. IntelliJ IDEA VM options (Help | Edit Custom VM Options) have no effect on the VM options of the apps you start from IntelliJ IDEA. These are only for the IDE runtime JVM, not for your own apps that you develop.
2. Post a screenshot of the run/debug configuration showing the VM options field. What type of the configuration is that? It's possible that you have defined global system environment variables that set the initial heap size to some large value (`-Xms`). Make sure you don't have `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variables set. If you do, remove them and logout/login or reboot for the changes to apply.
3. If the project is imported from Maven and you are running tests, `pom.xml` may supply the VM options, search `pom.xml` for for `-Xms` and either remove this option or make it lower than `-Xmx`.
4. If the project is Gradle based and you run it via Gradle, the options you have defined in `gradle.properties` via `org.gradle.jvmargs` will have effect. Make sure you don't override `-Xms` there. You can also [switch to IntelliJ IDEA run option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7Sk.png) to not use Gradle options.

Comment: I have only 3 parameters in VM Arguments :
-Denv.type
-Xmx
-Dlogfile.configuration
I have checked env'al variables and both _JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS are not there.

Comment: Post the full command line from the Run console when the app is started. Did you check point #2 about the global environment variables?

Comment: This from Run console : ----> Task xyz.main() Failed
Error occured during initialization of VM
 Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size

Comment: its a gradle project and nothing is passed from gradle build file

Comment: See #4 I've added.

Comment: When I remove Xmx property from application VM argument run configuration it runs fine. However, when start my all services I get java out of memory error.